# Xamarin Listview Selected item Background color change with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

I was unable to change background color of selected item in ListView on longpress in Xamarin Forms.I used Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme for my app. Please find the below options which made in style.xml .

```
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">#c00e0e</item>
<item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">#33cc33</item>
<item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">#0052cc</item>
<item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">#ffff00</item>
</style>
```